# Сортировка для картинок php mysql

Tags: php, sql

Делаю множественную загрузку картинок через форму.
Идея в том, чтобы вынести изображения для товаров в отдельную таблицу.

```
product-id  | image | sort
```

Как правильно сделать так, чтобы сортировка (sort), в случае загрузки нескольких картинок была от 1 и добавлялось +1 с каждой итерацией цикла для каждого id товара.

```
product-id  | image | sort
1           | a.jpg | 1
1           | b.jpg | 2
1           | c.jpg | 3
2           | d.jpg | 1
2           | e.jpg | 2
```

Пробовал так, но что-то не работает:

```
foreach ($normalizeImages as $image) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE product_id='$id' ORDER BY sort DESC LIMIT 1";
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){ 
foreach($result as $row){ 
$exsort = $row["sort"]; 
} 
$result->free(); } else{ echo "Ошибка: " . $conn->error;}

if($exsort=='') {
$sort = 1;
} else if($exsort!='') { 
$sort = $exsort++;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO images (product_id, image, sort) VALUES ('$id','$filetodb','$sort')";
if($conn->query($sql)){ } else { echo "Ошибка" . $conn->error;}

}
```

Comment: Указывайте точно какой sql вы используете, от этого зависит способ реализации (MSSQL \MySQL \PGSQL\...)

Comment: И не забудьте указать точную версию используемой СУБД.

Comment: *Как правильно сделать так, чтобы сортировка (sort), в случае загрузки нескольких картинок была от 1 и добавлялось +1 с каждой итерацией цикла для каждого id товара.* Вот это показанное желаемое - это должен быть результат выполнения запроса или это должно быть содержимое таблицы? ели второе, то что должно происходить, если запись (например, `b.jpg`) удаляется - перенумерация?

Comment: Akina, нужно чтобы при добавлении одного товара и загрузки нескольких картинок, они нумеровались для каждого отдельного товара 1.2.3... При добавлении следующего товара, нумерация в той же таблице для нового id опять начиналась с 1.2.3.. удаление записи не имеет значения, так как нужно их нумеровать только в момент загрузки. К вопросу от Владимира, я знаю, что в MyISAM и BDB можно определить AUTO_INCREMENT для вторичного столбца, но у меня MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($normalizeImages as $key => $image) {
```

$key - индекс элемента массива (картинок) с 0
вот его и записывать в поле sort.
можно $key+1 как в примере, но это ни к чему.